# Preference of MOS resistor as load in MOS inverter

Tags: mosfet, cmos, inverter, vlsi, nmos

Whys is a MOS resistor preferred over diffused resistor as load in design of a MOS inverter?

Comment: Who says it is?

Comment: IIRC a MOS resistor could be made much smaller than a plain resistor.

Comment: Looks like the " It's not my area of experience so therefore it's not EE" brigade is in full force again.  This is a perfectly compact and reasonable question.  Think of it as on opportunity to teach something.

Comment: @placeholder It's a reasonable question, but I feel it needs more context to stay open. As in, "Source x indicates MOS is preferred, why?"